# Reading beyond buffer

Tags: io, go

I have a buffer of size `bufferSize` from which I read in chunks of `blockSize`, however, this yields some (to me) unexpected behavior, when the `blockSize` goes beyond the `bufferSize`.

I've put the code here:

http://play.golang.org/p/Ra2jicYHPu

Why does the second chunk only give 4 bytes? What's happening here?

I'd expect `Read` to always give the amount of bytes `len(byteArray)`, and if it goes beyond the buffer, it'll handle that situation by setting the pointer in the buffer to after `byteArray`, and putting the rest of the buffer + whatever is beyond until the new buffer pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations are not based on any documented behavior of `bufio.Reader`. If you want *"Read to always give the amount of bytes len(byteArray)"* you must use [io.ReadAtLeast](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadAtLeast).

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "strings"
)

const bufSize = 10
const blockSize = 12

func main() {
        s := strings.NewReader("some length test string buffer boom")
        buffer := bufio.NewReaderSize(s, bufSize)

        b := make([]byte, blockSize)
        n, err := io.ReadAtLeast(buffer, b, blockSize)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("First read got %d bytes: %s\n", n, string(b))

        d := make([]byte, blockSize)
        n, err = io.ReadAtLeast(buffer, d, blockSize)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Second read got %d bytes: %s\n", n, string(d))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/8phVDdVIoL)

---

Output:

```
First read got 12 bytes: some length 
Second read got 12 bytes: test string
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it. It makes sense why Read, as a more low-level function, would only go to the limit of the buffer as well.

Comment: Also worth checking `io.ReadFull` and `ioutil.ReadAll`.

Comment: @skinkelynet, I would add that Go is (luckily) pretty low-level in its basic features while providing more higher-level utilities when you need them. This feature of `io.Read()` not filling the whole buffer actually matches the semantics of the [`read(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) POSIX syscall which uses its buffer size parameter only to know the *upper* limit on the bytes it can acquire from the underlying layer and return; the lower limit is one byte (for blocking calls, and 0 for non-blocking calls or in case of an error).

Answer (score 0):

1.see the code of buffio.NewReaderSize

```
func NewReaderSize(rd io.Reader, size int) *Reader {
    // Is it already a Reader?
    b, ok := rd.(*Reader)
    if ok && len(b.buf) >= size {
        return b
    }
    if size < minReadBufferSize {
        size = minReadBufferSize
    }
    return &Reader{
        buf:          make([]byte, size),
        rd:           rd,
        lastByte:     -1,
        lastRuneSize: -1,
    }
}
```

strings.NewReader return a strings.Reader,so the buffer's  (returned by bufio.NewReaderSize ) buf has minReadBufferSize（val is 16）
2.see code of bufio.Read

```
func (b *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    ……
    copy(p[0:n], b.buf[b.r:])
    b.r += n
    b.lastByte = int(b.buf[b.r-1])
    b.lastRuneSize = -1
    return n, nil
}
```

copy src is b.buf[**b.r**:]，when your first Read,b.r=12,……